# react-table get default email address from multiple email addresses in data (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I want to be able to access the default email from data received from an API

I have a data represented like so:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "firstName": "Man",
  "lastName": "Stranger",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "email": "manStranger1@gmail.com",
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "email": "manStranger2@gmail.com",
      "isDefault": false
    },
}
```

Currently I can only show emails in my react-table like this:

```
  const columns: Array<any> = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'emailAddresses[0].email',
      },
    ],
    [],
  );
```

However, it is not guaranteed that I [0] is always the default email.
Normally I would get the default email with something like this:

```
data.emailAddresses.filter((x) =>
 x.isDefault === true).map((data: MemberDataStore.EmailAddresses, index) =>
 data.email
```

But this method doesnt work with react-table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Cell` and use `Array.find` method on **original** `row` data:

```
{
  id: 'defaultEmail', // Write some unique id as we don't have accessor 
  Header: 'Email',
  Cell: ({row}) => (
    <span>
      {row.original.emailAddresses.find((e) => e.isDefault)?.email ??
        'No default email'}
    </span>
  ),
},
```

And if you are getting TS warning of *implicitly has an 'any' type* for `row` and `e`, you can fix the typings:

```
import {Column} from 'react-table'
const columns = useMemo<Column[]>(
  () => [
    { 
      // ..
      Cell: ({row}) => {
        const {emailAddresses} = row.original as InterfaceOrTypeOfData
        return (<span>
          {emailAddresses.find((e) => e.isDefault)?.email ?? 'No default email'}
        </span>)
      }
    },
    // ...
  ],
  [],
);
```

Comment: I tried this method, but I get a parameter ' ' implicitly has an 'any' type error under row and e

Comment: I do have an interface defined elsewhere, yes - but not in this file (as the api is used in multiple places)